# How to scale all objects inside a SpriteKit Scene

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer, skspritenode

I have a SpriteKit scene (`MyScene : SKScene<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>`) in which I put 4 animals (all `SKSpriteNode *sprite`).

I'd like to scale all the 4 animals with a single pinch action applied on the background (the scene itself), but it doesn't work. I mean: `xScale` and `yScale` of the scene get updated, but all the animals inside does not, they always remain in the same position and the same original scale.

I partially solved this problem by putting the 4 animals inside a specific `SKSpriteNode* background` instead of putting them directly in the scene and in this case, if I scale the `background`, all the animals inside the `background` get scaled automatically, but I need to remove this background and this does not happen it I scale the original scene.

What am I doing it wrong? here below my code

```
- (IBAction)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        CGPoint touchLocation = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];
        touchLocation = [self convertPointFromView:touchLocation];
        [self selectNodeForTouch:touchLocation]; //here the "_selectedNode" is set to an animal or to the scene itself
        [recognizer setScale:_selectedNode.xScale];

    }
    else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        _selectedNode.xScale = recognizer.scale;
        _selectedNode.yScale = recognizer.scale;

    }
    else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        NSLog(@"pinch gesture ended");
    }

}
```

Comment: Why does it have to be a background,  just shove them all into an SKNode and scale the node

Comment: BTW scaling the scene will not work because scenes are designed to autoscale to fit the view at all times.  How it autoscales depends on scaleMode

Comment: so should I create a fake empty SkNode and put everything inside it and manage scaling over it?

Comment: sure, if you want all nodes inside of it to scale at the same time.  Do note that this will cause a zoom effect, it will not keep all sprites in the same position and scale